# AR Camera Crashes

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I am having an issue with the AR Camera in Tango crashing after a few minutes. I am using Unity 5.5.0 f3 release. I have updated to the latest Tango Core on the Phab 2 Pro as well as updated to the most recent SDK as of today(Gankino).

When the AR Camera crashes it just freezes in the background but all my AR still continues to run just fine and app functions as it is suppose to with no problem.

There is no updated AR Camera for Tango in this release. They use the deprecated one in their examples.

Comment: Currently a lot of developers are experiencing the same issues with the `Ganiko` build. I advise you to downgrade to the previous build and wait for the error to be fixed.

Comment: I was originally on a lower version of Tango. Did it on the old version as well as this one. But seems to be only doing it on the Phab 2 Pro and not the Tango Dev Tablet I have.

Comment: What version of `Tango` did you test on the phab? and with what version of `Unity` did you test?

Comment: I can't remember the first tango version but it was downloaded in January and the one that is currently on tango site for download. Unity I tried version 5.5.0 f3 and 5.5.1. Nut like I said. So far I've tested on 5 phab devices is have and 2 tango tablets. AR camera crashes on the phabs not the tango tablets. So I'm guessing these phab devices aren't tested with Google. Cause they have a lot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the bug report, we would like to understand the cause of the crashing - a logcat would be useful.

We merged the AR camera prefab functionality into a single Tango Camera prefab that has support for AR as well. We marked the old AR camera prefab as deprecated but it uses some scripts that were modified for the new Tango Camera prefab. It is possible we introduced this bug, but a repro would be useful.